# Export chart.js into fixed sized chart

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, chart.js

I am trying to get an image (for instance png) out of a chart drawn with chart.js.
The idea is to send this image to the backend to then include it in a larger report.

Generating an image out of the canvas of the chart is quite easy - I can do something like

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasIwantToRenderForTheBackend');
canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
// or
canvas.getImageData();
```

The problem I have is that this will make the chart-image look the way it looks in the moment when the user is creating the report.

What I need is to create a fixed size canvas, draw the chart in there and export that canvas to the image - basically I don't want the image to be squeezed just because the user made the browser window smaller and it looks squeezed in the browser (chartjs tries to make the chart look "nice" within the squeezed frame it gets). Also I don't want the canvas the user is seeing to get resized or do strange things.

p.s.: I tried making a copy of the canvas which I don't append to the DOM, resize that and then generate the image out of that - but that somehow is just an empty image.
Actually, I tried to just manipulate the width of the canvas in the browser-console and the chart disappears

p.p.s.: Note that I don't want to resize the image - I can do that, I want to resize the canvas where chartjs draws the chart because depending on the size of the canvas the chart looks different - I want the image which I get to be independent of what the user is seeing right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I am using is to create my fixed size canvas in the DOM but I position it outside of the visible screen.

Basically I put the canvas I want to use to render an image out of it inside the following div

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: -2000px">
 <canvas id="canvasIwantToRenderForTheBackend" <!-- here go all the attrs I want to use for this canvas--> ></canvas>
</div>
```

This way chartjs gets forced to actually render the chart into that canvas.